# How to resolve error remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open many pdfs in specific folder using word document and copy the contents and paste in my excel sheet without format change. The code which i have written was able to perform the task for 2 pdf files only after that it is showing run time error 462 - The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable. Kindly help me what is going wrong and how i can resolve it? Thanks in advance.

```
Sub test()
Dim s As String
Dim path As String
Dim col As Integer: col = 1
Dim t As Excel.Range
    path = "C:\Users\121919\Desktop\Direct Dispatch Report_PENS\29 Jul\PDF to Word Try\"
    s = Dir(path & "*.pdf")


Do Until s = ""
    Dim wd As New Word.Application
    Dim mydoc As Word.document

    Set mydoc = Word.Documents.Open(Filename:=path & s, Format:="PDF Files", ConfirmConversions:=False)
    Dim wr As Word.Range
    Set wr = mydoc.Paragraphs(1).Range

    wr.WholeStory
    Set t = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    wr.Copy
    t.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    mydoc.Close False: s = Dir

    wd.Quit '<- This is where the code stops and throw error

Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need `wd`? You don't seem to use it anywhere. Perhaps you've meant `mydoc = wd.Documents.Open(Filename:=path & s, Format:="PDF Files", ConfirmConversions:=False)` ?

Comment: Thank you so much. after removing those wd codes, it is working fine. Thanks again.